# R session crashes grouping and summarizing large dataset using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following code. It runs perfectly fine on this toy data set. But, when I apply the exact same code to a large 7.5 million dataset with 2.5 million unique accountIds, it keeps crashing the R session repeatedly.

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong? Should I be doing something different to make dplyr scale better?

```
library(dplyr)

fakedata <- data.frame(accountId = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5),
                       amount = c(22.5, 22.5, 22.5, 59, 82, 102, 44,
                                  44, 64, 64, 202.5, 202.5),
                       date = c('2014-01-03', '2014-02-03', '2014-03-04',
                                '2015-04-01', '2015-05-01', '2014-02-08',
                                '2012-10-06', '2012-11-06', '2012-12-06',
                                '2013-01-06', '2014-06-02', '2014-09-03'))

fakedata

repeats <- fakedata %>%
  group_by(accountId) %>%
  summarise(repeated = n(), repeatb = (repeated > 1),
            diffamt = (n_distinct(amount) > 1),
            initamt = amount[which.min(date)],
            lastamt = amount[which.max(date)],
            higheramt = (lastamt > initamt))

repeats
```

Comment: Two thoughts:  *(1)* could you be doing something as basic as "running out of memory?"  *(2)* does it make a difference if the input data is first *sorted* by accountID?

Comment: Sorting did not help. Memory could be a problem, but I have 8GB on my MacBook and nothing serious is running. The 7.5 million dataset is using (according to pryr::mem_used()) about 600MB. Is there a way to pre-calculate memory needs of the drplyr pipeline?

Comment: I'm afraid that I can't help you any further on this one.  (When it crashes, *how* does it "crash?")  I see nothing obviously wrong with the program, and a 600MB dataset should be no-problem on an 8GB MacBook.

Comment: Studio says "R Session Aborted" with that "bomb" image. Only option is to re-start and re-run, with same results.

Comment: have you tried data.table?

Comment: Can you try removing some of the calculations in summarise call to see if there is particular call which is problematic? Or more generally break up this computation into easier to debug chunks so it becomes more clear what is making R crash.

Comment: Interesting thought, Henk ... and, if you needed to write an "Answer" to, say, include some R-code that expresses your idea, that would seem fine to me.  Maybe it's just too much for a "Frame."